# Implement memcopy

Tags: c, arrays, string, memcpy

I was asked to implement my own version of memcopy.  This is what I found from the internet. The thing confuses me is that we have two `void *` pointers, why do we then typecast them onto   `char*`?

Is this even correct?

```
// A C implementation of memcpy()
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


    void myMemCpy(void *dest, void *src, size_t n)
    {
       // Typecast src and dest addresses to (char *)
       char *csrc = (char *)src;
       char *cdest = (char *)dest;

       // Copy contents of src[] to dest[]
       for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
           cdest[i] = csrc[i];
    }
```

Comment: It is funny "I was asked to implement my own version of memcopy. This is what I found from the internet.":)

Comment: Technically it should be `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

Comment: @Anni_housie  Maybe you mean memcpy?:)

Comment: @EOF Sure, but there's another mistake that's far most likely to cause problems.

Comment: @hvd: What's a bit of `signed/unsigned` comparison between friends? Oh, a disaster you say?

Comment: Yes, I mean memcpy.

Comment: @EOF : why `unsigned char` ?

Comment: @Anni_housie  This "I was asked to implement my own version of memcopy. This is what I found from the internet.": looks like "I was asked to add 2 and 2. This 2 + 2 = 3 is what I found from the internet":) It is a modern approach!:)

Comment: @shrike: 'Cause the standard says so: C11 draft standard n1570: *7.24 String handling <string.h>
7.24.1 String function conventions 3 For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type
unsigned char (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a
different value).*

Comment: @EOF : ok, did not know, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Your argument declarations are wrong. See the standard for the correct signature of `memcpy`.

Answer (score 3):

The cast is needed because you may not dereference pointers of the type `void *`. Thus you may not for example to write `src[i]` when `src` is a pointer of the type `void *`. The type void is an incomplete type.

As for the function then it is wrong.

If you look at the declaration of the standard function `memcpy` you will see that it is declared like

```
void * memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void * restrict s2, size_t n);
^^^^^^                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Thus the function written by you should look at least like

```
void * memcpy(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n);
```

The function definition can look as it is shown in this demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void * myMemCpy(void *s1, const void *s2, size_t n)
{
    const unsigned char *src = s2;
    unsigned char *dsn = s1;

    while ( n-- ) *dsn++ = *src++;

    return s1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s1[] = "Hello";
    char s2[sizeof( s1 )];

    puts( ( char * )myMemCpy( s2, s1, sizeof( s1 ) ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
```

Comment: @EOF It is a typo. Thanks.:)

Comment: If you really *are* thankful, you'll remove the hideous and useless `!= 0` in the `while()`-condition. I've been using too much C# and Java recently, I don't want my beautiful C sullied like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast them because the "type" `void` doesn't have a size (mind `void *` does).

Then your loop will be able to move one `char` (ideally a byte) at a time.